# Phone number validation in a Javascript for a specific format on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

> Javascript

```
var format = (555)555-5555

"keypress #clientphonenumber": function (event) {
        var keycode = event.which;
        if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 37 || keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
            event.preventDefault();
             $("#modaldescription2").empty();
            $("#modaldescription2").append("<b>Only Numbers are allowed</b>");
            $('#dialogPanel2').modal({
                dimmerSettings: {
                    variation: 'inverted'
                }
            }).modal("show");
        }
    },
```

> Html

```
<div class="field">
       <b>Client Phone Number</b>
       <input type="text" id="clientphonenumber" value="<%- clientphonenumber%>">
    </div>
```

I need to validate a phone number on keypress using the above format i had tried above method but it not accepting `()` and `-` . can anyone help me with this

Comment: My phone number does not fit in your format. Am I not allowed to use your service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: please make it an executable js function

Comment: @empiric those things doesn't work on keypress